# Получаю данные с Firebase база данных FireStore получаю список в RecyclerView . Нужно при нажатии на элемент списка открывать новую Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

Адаптер:

```
public class OldersAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Olders, OldersAdapter.OldersHolder> {
    private Context mContext;

    public OldersAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Olders> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.mContext = context;

    }





    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(OldersHolder holder, int position, Olders model) {
        holder.textViewNumber.setText(model.getNumber());
        holder.textViewDevice.setText(model.getDevice());
        holder.textViewFirm.setText("Фирма: "+ model.getFirm());
        holder.textViewModel.setText("Модель: " + model.getModel());
        holder.textViewCost.setText("Стоймость: " + model.getCost());
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
        holder.open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, order_overview.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public OldersHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.zakaz, group, false);
        return new OldersHolder(view);

    }

    static class OldersHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewNumber;
        TextView textViewModel;
        TextView textViewFirm;
        TextView textViewCost;
        TextView textViewDevice;
        ImageView open;
        public OldersHolder(View i) {
            super(i);
            textViewNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
            textViewDevice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
            textViewFirm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
            textViewModel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView20);
            textViewCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
            open = itemView.findViewById(R.id.open);
        }
    }
}
```

Передаю адаптер на Activity

```
 private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = db.collection("User").whereEqualTo("status", false).orderBy("number", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Olders> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Olders>()
                .setQuery(query, Olders.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new OldersAdapter(options);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(adapter!=null) {
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
```

Logcat:
adapter = new OldersAdapter(options);
^
required: FirestoreRecyclerOptions,Context
found: FirestoreRecyclerOptions
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Судя по ошибке вы забыли передать контекст там, где вы создаёте адаптер. А вообще, контекст вам передавать не надо, его можно из вьюхи получить. Например так: `v.getContext()`

Comment: я не знаю как правильно написать

Comment: Удалите контекст из конструктора, удалите переменную контекста из класса и вместо неё используйте v.getContext()